# How to deal with indexing involving three vectors?

Tags: matlab

I have the following three vectors:

`trans_now=[1 2 4];  data2send=[1 0 0 1];  datasent=[0 0 0 0];`

I want to set `datasent` to `1` for those nodes that are members of `tran_now` and whose `data2send` status is `1`. e.g 4 is a member of `trans_now` and `data2send(4)` is `1` therefore `datasent(4)` should be set to `1`.

I can do it using for loop and if statement as shown in the code below.

```
for i=1:length(trans_now)
    if data2send(trans_now(i))==1
        datasent(trans_now(i))=1;
    end
end
```

However I want one liner code for this. The one liner code that I tried is

`req_sent(req2send(trans_now)==1)=1;`

But it doesn't work. 
The output should set `datasent` vector to `[1 0 0 1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could solve this in 2 ways:

**1.**

```
data_sent(trans_now) = data2send(trans_now)
```

the output is:

> data_sent =
>        1     0     0     1

In this solution I assumed that all the initial values of `data_sent` are starting as `0` and that you need to assign it once.

**2.**

```
datasent(intersect(find(data2send == 1), trans_now)) = 1
```

output is:

> data_sent =
>        1     0     0     1

In this solution no assumption is used and you assign only indices where `data2send == 1` and also appear in `trans_now`

Comment: i think there is a second `=` missing in your first version

Comment: @Finn there isn't, I assign the values not using boolean expression. look at the assumption I wrote on that solution option

Comment: ahhh, i see. ty